# Theoretically compute expected out of sample performance of a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

It is common practice to use a test set to find an estimate of the expected out of sample performance the learned network. Is there a theoretical method to get such an estimate ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the theoretical bounds are not tight enough to be practically useful.

Comment: Are you familiar with the PRESS statistic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic